How to combine environmental data with different temporal coverage
I have several types of data in raster format that I would like to combine into a single raster with several layers to facilitate data extraction and generate predictions:
•   Future climate data (RCP 4.5 and RCP 8.5) for each year from 2021 to 2100.
•   Anthropogenic data (SSP1, SSP2, SSP3, SSP4, SSP5) for the years 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050, 2055, 2060, 2065, 2070, 2075, 2080, 2085, 2090, 2095, and 2100.
•   Land cover data (SSP2 - RCP4.5, SSP5 - RCP8.5) for the years 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050, 2055, 2060, 2065, 2070, 2075, 2080, 2085, 2090, 2095, and 2100.
•   Ecoregion data (RCP 4.5 and RCP 8.5) for the years 2050 and 2080.
As you can see, I don’t have data for all years similarly to the climate data, and the climate projection scenarios are not the same. Also, I’m unsure about how to combine them, especially since I don’t have data for every year.
Here’s an example for the scenario RCP 4.5. For instance, the first row means that I combined the climate raster for 2021 and RCP 4.5, the land cover raster for 2025 and SSP2 - RCP4.5, the anthropogenic raster for 2025 and SSP2, and the ecoregion raster for 2050 and RCP 4.5 to form the final raster for 2021 and SSP2 - RCP4.5.
Does this approach seem correct to you? Any advice would be greatly appreciated since I’m new to GIS.
   SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2021_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2021_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2025_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2025_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2022_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2022_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2025_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2025_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2023_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2023_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2025_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2025_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2024_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2024_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2025_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2025_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2025_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2025_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2025_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2025_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2026_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2026_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2030_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2030_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2027_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2027_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2030_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2030_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2028_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2028_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2030_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2030_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2029_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2029_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2030_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2030_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2030_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2030_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2030_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2030_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2031_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2031_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2035_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2035_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2032_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2032_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2035_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2035_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2033_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2033_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2035_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2035_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2034_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2034_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2035_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2035_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2035_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2035_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2035_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2035_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2036_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2036_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2040_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2040_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2037_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2037_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2040_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2040_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2038_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2038_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2040_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2040_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2039_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2039_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2040_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2040_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2040_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2040_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2040_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2040_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2041_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2041_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2045_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2045_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2042_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2042_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2045_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2045_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2043_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2043_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2045_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2045_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2044_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2044_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2045_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2045_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2045_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2045_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2045_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2045_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2046_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2046_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2050_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2050_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2047_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2047_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2050_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2050_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2048_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2048_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2050_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2050_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2049_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2049_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2050_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2050_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2050_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2050_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2050_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2050_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2050_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2051_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2051_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2055_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2055_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2052_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2052_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2055_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2055_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2053_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2053_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2055_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2055_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2054_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2054_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2055_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2055_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2055_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2055_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2055_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2055_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2056_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2056_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2060_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2060_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2057_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2057_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2060_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2060_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2058_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2058_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2060_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2060_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2059_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2059_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2060_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2060_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2060_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2060_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2060_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2060_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2061_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2061_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2065_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2065_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2062_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2062_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2065_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2065_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2063_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2063_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2065_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2065_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2064_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2064_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2065_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2065_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2065_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2065_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2065_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2065_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2066_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2066_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2070_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2070_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2067_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2067_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2070_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2070_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2068_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2068_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2070_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2070_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2069_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2069_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2070_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2070_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2070_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2070_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2070_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2070_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2071_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2071_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2075_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2075_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2072_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2072_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2075_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2075_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2073_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2073_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2075_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2075_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2074_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2074_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2075_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2075_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2075_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2075_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2075_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2075_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2076_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2076_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2080_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2080_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2077_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2077_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2080_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2080_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2078_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2078_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2080_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2080_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2079_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2079_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2080_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2080_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raste)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2080_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2080_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2080_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2080_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2081_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2081_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2085_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2085_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2082_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2082_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2085_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2085_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2083_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2083_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2085_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2085_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2084_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2084_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2085_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2085_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2085_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2085_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2085_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2085_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2086_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2086_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2090_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2090_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2087_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2087_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2090_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2090_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2088_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2088_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2090_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2090_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2089_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2089_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2090_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2090_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2090_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2090_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2090_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2090_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2091_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2091_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2095_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2095_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2092_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2092_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2095_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2095_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2093_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2093_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2095_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2095_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2094_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2094_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2095_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2095_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2095_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2095_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2095_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2095_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2096_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2096_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2100_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2100_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2097_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2097_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2100_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2100_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2098_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2098_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2100_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2100_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2099_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2099_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2100_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2100_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)
    SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2100_raster <- c(RCP_4.5_2100_climate_raster, SSP_2_RCP_4.5_2100_land_cover_raster, SSP_2_2100_anthropogenic_raster, RCP_4.5_2080_ecoregion_raster)

